# how do I define a number->string dictionary in Typescript?

Tags: typescript

I'm playing with Typescript and converting over a small library over to it from Javascript.  In one area of the code there was a statically defined mapping of friendly key name to their keycode.  The original code looked like:

```
keys: { "Backspace": 8, "Tab": 9, "Enter": 13, ....etc.. };
```

I defined this in typescript via:

```
static keys: { [name: string]: number; } = { "Backspace": 8, "Tab": 9, "Enter": 13, ... etc.. };
```

This seems to work fine, however another part of the code uses the opposite mapping:

```
    chars: {8:"Backspace",9:"Tab",13:"Enter", ...etc... };
```

So I tried to do the same type of definition in typescript that I did previously:

```
chars: { [code: number]: string; } = { 8: "Backspace", 9: "Tab", 13: "Enter", ...etc.. };
```

This fails to compile with the following error:

> Cannot convert '{ 0: string; 1: string; 2: string; 4: string; 8: string; 9: string; : string; }' to '{ [name: number]: string; }': Index signatures of types '{ 0: string; 1: string; 2: string; 4: string; 8: string; 9: string; : string; }' and '{ [name: number]: string; }' are incompatible

How do I define this mapping in Typescript?

Answer (score 13):

The problem is that in JavaScript - and hence in TypeScript - the keys of an object literal are always strings, and so it cannot be assigned to a variable with a number indexer.

An object with a number indexer is an array - and so you have to do this:

```
var chars: string[] = [];
chars[8]= "Backspace";
chars[9]= "Tab";
chars[13] = "Enter";
```

Comment: Does this cause any issues with memory allocation? Like if you assigned something to `chars[10000000]` which in a dict/map in other languages would be fine but seems potentially problematic with this array approach.

Comment: Don't think so - Javascript (=Typescipt) arrays are stored like dictionaries, without allocating memory for the indexes without a value

Answer (score 2):

Indeed js internally only has string based indices (with Array being different from {}) but string / number conversion is stable in js :

```
var x = {0 : "asdf",1:"bb"} 
alert(x[0])
alert(x[1])
```

I think typescript should support it as well and created a work item you can vote on: http://typescript.codeplex.com/workitem/832

Answer (score 2):

[Here's a library called Classical.js](https://github.com/drubino/Classical)* that may help you accomplish this and similar problems. It defines, among other things, a doubly generic dictionary. For your use case, the code would look like this:

```
import c = Classical.Collections;

var keys = new c.Dictionary<string, number>();
keys.add("Backspace", 8);
keys.add("Tab", 9);
keys.add("Enter", 13);
//etc...

keys.getValue("Backspace"); //8
keys.getValue("Tab"); //9
keys.getValue("Enter"); //13
//etc...
```

Dictionary<TKey, TValue> works with all types of objects and doesn't have issues with name collisions such as keys named 'constructor'.

For the opposite mapping you could either construct the inverse dictionary or query the current one like so:

```
keys.query().single(pair => pair.key === 8).value; //"Backspace"
keys.query().single(pair => pair.key === 9).value; //"Tab"
keys.query().single(pair => pair.key === 13).value; //"Enter"
//etc...
```

If you'd like to give it a try, visit [Classical](https://github.com/drubino/Classical), open up the bin folder and add classical.js and classical.d.ts to your project.

Hope that helps.

---

* I am one of the developers on the classical team

Answer (score 1):

As of 2022 and TypeScript v4.7,

```
chars: { [code: number]: string } = { 8: "Backspace", ... etc.. }
```

works without errors.